# Why is ListView not populating with DataSource?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I am making a Windows Store App.
In the XAML main page I have a ListView and I am trying to bind it to observable collection in the code behind file.

But what I see is a blank screen.
Why is the list not populating ?

**EDIT:**

I am making an app to display names of some UI controls in XAML and I will later on add click events on each row of the list to go to a new page showing a demo of that control, thats why I used the name Control for model. I am making my own simple Kitchen Sink app.

Here is the **MainPage.xaml**:

```
<ListView x:Name="listOfControls" ItemsSource="{Binding controlsDataSource}" SelectionChanged="listOfControls_SelectionChanged">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding desc}"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

and Here is the **MainPage.xaml.cs**

Note: The term Control being used in the code is a name given by me to a model class which has got nothing to do with a UI Control.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234238

namespace AllControls
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private ObservableCollection<AllControls.Models.Control> controlsDataSource { get; set; }
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.controlsDataSource = new ObservableCollection<AllControls.Models.Control>();
            this.controlsDataSource.Add(new AllControls.Models.Control("ScrollViewer", "ScrollViewer Desc"));
            this.controlsDataSource.Add(new AllControls.Models.Control("ScrollViewer", "ScrollViewer Desc"));
            this.controlsDataSource.Add(new AllControls.Models.Control("ScrollViewer", "ScrollViewer Desc"));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.  The Parameter
        /// property is typically used to configure the page.</param>
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        void listOfControls_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Model, **Control.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AllControls.Models
{
    class Control
    {
        private String name{ get;set;}
        private String desc { get; set; }
        public Control(String iName, String iDesc)
        {
            name = iName;
            desc = iDesc;

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I am making an app to display names of some UI controls in XAML and I will later on add click events on each row of the list to go to a new page showing a demo of that control, thats why I used the name Control for model.
I am making my own simple Kitchen Sink app.

Comment: je kahi lihayachay question babat, direct question madhye lihit ja

Comment: niruttar aahet sagale tumachya prashna pudhe !!!

Answer (score 0):

So, I got it to work.

In the XAML,

Instead of `ItemsSource="{Binding controlsDataSource}"`, I specified just `ItemsSource="{Binding}`

and then in the MainPage Constructor in the code-behind file, I set the DataContext of the listView control to the Array programmatically.

```
public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.controlsDataSource = new ObservableCollection<AllControls.Models.Control>();
            this.controlsDataSource.Add(new AllControls.Models.Control("ScrollViewer", "ScrollViewer Desc"));
            this.controlsDataSource.Add(new AllControls.Models.Control("ScrollViewer", "ScrollViewer Desc"));
            this.controlsDataSource.Add(new AllControls.Models.Control("ScrollViewer", "ScrollViewer Desc"));
            listOfControls.DataContext = controlsDataSource;      
  }
```

Also I had kept the name  and desc properties as private which I made public, may be that was the actual change needed.
I thought that private will make the variables private and set and get will tell if they can be accessible but later on I realized that private outside was making the setter as private as well.

Thats it.

This was another way of accomplishing what I needed, but there should be a way to specify the dataSource List in the markup.

More answers are welcome but till then anyone.